# Conceptual question about how my ASP.net Web API responds to requests from AngularJS

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, routes, conceptual

### Conceptual question about how Angular.js works with my Web API to fetch data and update view

I'm new to Web development and I'm trying to solidify my concepts, so this is more of a theoretical question thaa a programming one. I implemented a ASP.net Web App with a Web API to fetch data from a database and used Angular.js for the front-end UI. My application is a simple database consisting of students and their info. All I'm doing is displaying the info using Angular.js and Web API. This question is about how the flow actually works to update the data in the database after a user submits a form on the UI.

Steps:

1. User clicks on the save button on the Student page after filling out the form.
2. This save button which has a ng-click() event handler associated with it will now go to the associated controller which is StudentCtrl.js. StudentCtrl.js has the CrudService as a dependency as well as some $scope variables
3. Now the data binding happens in the .SaveUpdate() function to bind whatever was submitted in the textbox into the dataModel which is 'student' in this case.
4. After this, a base url + apiRoute is used to make an HttpPost request.
5. The HttpPost request is made to CrudService.js so that it can pass this data to the server to save it.
6. The CrudService.js will now trigger the correct http method. In this case, it calls the post() method passing the route and the dataModel containing the data.
7. StudentApiController.cs now receives a request to do a post() action by CrudService.js which awaits a response from it.
8. StudentApiController will now use its save method and manipulate the data using the dbContext
9. Once the StudentAPIController is done, it returns a response back with HttpStatusMesssage to CrudService.js
10. CrudService.js now returns a response to StudentCtrl.js which checks if the response is acceptable and presents a new view to the user which shows the newly added student.

Questions:

1. Is this how the flow actually works from the time the user hits the save button to when it is actually saved in the database?
2. How does the dbContext end up manipulating the data? Does it cause some SQL queries to be created? I remember reading something about this because Entity framework creates SQL statements to do the actual updating.
3. There is a StudentController.cs file which returns View(). Where does this come in in the process I explained above?

### index.cshtml:

```
<form novalidate name="frmStudent" id="frmStudent" class="form-horizontal row-border">
    <br />
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="input17"> First Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <input type="text"
                       id="idFirstName"
                       class="form-control"
                       name="nameFirstName" ng-model="firstName" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="input17"> Last Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <input type="text"
                       id="idLastName"
                       class="form-control"
                       name="nameFirstName" ng-model="lasttName" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="input17"> Email</label>
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <input type="text"
                       id="idEmail"
                       class="form-control"
                       name="nameEmail" ng-model="email" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="input17"> Address</label>
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <input type="text"
                       id="idAddress"
                       class="form-control"
                       name="nameAdress" ng-model="address" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-4">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <span id="save" class="btn btn-success margin-right-btn"
                      ng-click="SaveUpdate()">
                    <i class="icon-save"></i> {{btnText}}
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

### StudentCtrl.js:

```
app.controller('StudentCtrl', ['$scope', 'CrudService',
    function ($scope, CrudService) {

        // Base Url 
        var baseUrl = '/api/StudentAPI/';
        $scope.btnText = "Save";
        $scope.studentID = 0;
        $scope.SaveUpdate = function () {
            var student = {
                FirstName: $scope.firstName,
                LastName: $scope.lasttName,
                Email: $scope.email,
                Address: $scope.address,
                StudentID: $scope.studentID
            }
            if ($scope.btnText == "Save") {
                var apiRoute = baseUrl + 'SaveStudent/';
                var saveStudent = CrudService.post(apiRoute, student);
                saveStudent.then(function (response) {
                    if (response.data != "") {
                        alert("Data Saved Successfully");
                        $scope.GetStudents();
                        $scope.Clear();

                    } else {
                        alert("Some error");
                    }

                }, function (error) {
                    console.log("Error: " + error);
                });
            }
            else {
                var apiRoute = baseUrl + 'UpdateStudent/';
                var UpdateStudent = CrudService.put(apiRoute, student);
                UpdateStudent.then(function (response) {
                    if (response.data != "") {
                        alert("Data Updated Successfully");
                        $scope.GetStudents();
                        $scope.Clear();

                    } else {
                        alert("Some error");
                    }

                }, function (error) {
                    console.log("Error: " + error);
                });
            }
        }

        $scope.Clear = function () {
            $scope.studentID = 0;
            $scope.firstName = "";
            $scope.lasttName = "";
            $scope.email = "";
            $scope.address = "";
        }

        $scope.GetStudents = function () {
            var apiRoute = baseUrl + 'GetStudents/';
            var student = CrudService.getAll(apiRoute);
            student.then(function (response) {
                $scope.students = response.data;

            },
                function (error) {
                    console.log("Error: " + error);
                });
        }
        $scope.GetStudents();
```

### CrudService.js

```
app.service('CrudService', function ($http) {

    var urlGet = '';
    this.post = function (apiRoute, Model) {
        var request = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: apiRoute,
            data: Model
        });
        return request;
    }
    this.put = function (apiRoute, Model) {
        var request = $http({
            method: "put",
            url: apiRoute,
            data: Model
        });
        return request;
    }
    this.delete = function (apiRoute) {
        var request = $http({
            method: "delete",
            url: apiRoute
        });
        return request;
    }
    this.getAll = function (apiRoute) {

        urlGet = apiRoute;
        return $http.get(urlGet);
    }
    this.getbyID = function (apiRoute, studentID) {

        urlGet = apiRoute + '/' + studentID;
        return $http.get(urlGet);
    }
});
```

### StudentAPIController.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using System.Data.Entity;
using CRUDOperations.Models;

namespace CRUDOperations.api
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/StudentAPI")]

    public class StudentAPIController : ApiController
    {
        StudentDBEntities dbContext = null;

        public StudentAPIController() {
            dbContext = new StudentDBEntities();
        }

        [ResponseType(typeof(tblStudent))]
        [HttpPost]
        //Saves a particular student in the database
        public HttpResponseMessage SaveStudent(tblStudent astudent) {
            int result = 0;
            try
            {
                dbContext.tblStudents.Add(astudent);
                dbContext.SaveChanges();
                result = 1;
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                result = 0;
            }
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
        }

        //Gets all the students from the database:
        [ResponseType(typeof(tblStudent))]
        [HttpGet]
        public List<tblStudent> GetStudents() {
            List<tblStudent> students = null;
            try {
                students = dbContext.tblStudents.ToList();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                students = null;
            }
            return students;
        }
        //For eg a complete route will be: /api/StudentAPI/GetStudentByID/2
        //Edit the student data:

        //Constraint that the studentID needs to be an int
        [Route("GetStudentByID/{studentID:int}")]
        [ResponseType(typeof(tblStudent))]
        [HttpGet]
        public tblStudent GetStudentByID(int studentID)
        {
            tblStudent astudent = null;
            try
            {
                astudent = dbContext.tblStudents.Where(x => x.StudentID == studentID).SingleOrDefault();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                astudent = null;
            }

            return astudent;
        }

        //Updating the student details:
        [ResponseType(typeof(tblStudent))]
        [HttpPut]
        public HttpResponseMessage UpdateStudent(tblStudent astudent) {
            int result = 0;
            try {
                dbContext.tblStudents.Attach(astudent);
                dbContext.Entry(astudent).State = EntityState.Modified;
                dbContext.SaveChanges();
                result = 1;
            } catch {
                result = 0;
            }
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,result);
        }



        //Delete the student:
        [Route("DeleteStudent/{studentID:int}")]
        [ResponseType(typeof(tblStudent))]
        [HttpDelete]
        public HttpResponseMessage DeleteStudent(int studentID) {
            int result = 0;
            try {
                var student = dbContext.tblStudents.Where(x => x.StudentID == studentID).FirstOrDefault();
                //Attach lets us update only that entity, not every field in the table.
                dbContext.tblStudents.Attach(student);
                dbContext.tblStudents.Remove(student);
                dbContext.SaveChanges();
                result = 1;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                result = 0;
            }
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
        }
    }
}
```

### StudentController.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace CRUDOperations.Controllers
{
    public class StudentController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Student
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult viewAllStudents() {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Way too much going on here and too many questions for anyone to spend any time on it. Try to narrow it down to one specific issue. Have a a look at [What sort of questions should I avoid asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: its just conceptual questions? The code is just to show you what's going on... Idk how to make this any shorter. The only issue is me confirming if my understanding about the flow is correct or not.